# Which is faster: SELECT DISTINCT or WHERE foo != 0?

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

```
id | foo | bar
--------------
0  | 0   | ...
1  | 1   | ...
2  | 2   | ...
3  | 0   | ...
4  | 2   | ...
```

I need all unique foo values, but not "0" which is in very often.

Which is faster?

```
SELECT foo FROM `table` WHERE foo != 0
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM `table`
```

The last would keep the 0 but be removed in PHP.

On my server both were fast enough but one of these two option might be theoretically faster :)

Comment: IN general DISTINCT is expensive.But to really see it you need 100 k +rows.Also depending on your data distribution even the first one can be .slow,but as a rule SELECT DISTINCT without a WHERE will be slow(er)

Comment: I'm confused. In your dataset, do you know that non-zero values are DISTINCT or not?

Comment: It depends. for example if you have a index on foo. But you have a good chance that it just not matters, as the communication between your program and the database is often slower than the difference.

Comment: The likelihood, is that the overhead of any post-processing will be costlier than a simple query - but the difference will be marginal.

Comment: Both queries result in different things. `where foo != 0` will just retrieve records (duplicate or not) where foo is not 0. `distinct` will remove duplicate records regardless of foo's value. Since `distinct` looks at entire content of the row, it is likely to be slower.

Comment: You guys are right, I'd need a `DISTINCT` in the first query as well... Always test with real life data :)

Comment: @zedfoxus To be clear, DISTINCT only looks at the selected columns.

Comment: Of course, you're only filtering out one row on a DISTINCT data set, and, (in the absence of an ORDER BY clause) on an indexed data set, this will be the first row in the php array. So you could just ignore that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an indexed data set of 130,000 rows. The sparse column has values in the range 0-100000. The dense column has values in the range 0-100.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+--------+-------+
| id | sparse | dense |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      0 |     0 |
|  2 |  52863 |    87 |
|  3 |  76503 |    21 |
|  4 |  77783 |    25 |
|  6 |  89359 |    73 |
|  7 |  97772 |    69 |
|  8 |  53429 |    59 |
|  9 |  35206 |    99 |
| 13 |  88062 |    44 |
| 14 |  56312 |    49 |
...

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sparse <> 0;
130941 rows in set (0.09 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE dense <> 0;
130289 rows in set (0.09 sec)

SELECT DISTINCT sparse FROM my_table;
72844 rows in set (0.27 sec)

SELECT DISTINCT dense FROM my_table;
101 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, whether or not DISTINCT is faster depends very much on the density of the data.

Obviously, in this instance, the two queries are very different from each other!

Comment: Ah ok, I have thousands of long IDs like youre sparse row. 10% are "0", some are doubled. In the end I want a PHP array of all unique ids. I could keep doubles without 0 and clean the array in PHP?

Comment: You could, but without trying, I couldn't say whether processing the array in PHP would be faster. My guess is that it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

As per the condition given in question, `distinct` will be expensive as it does sorting on all the records in a block fetched in main memory before eliminating the duplicate records while the `select` with `where` condition is going to iterate each record in the block only once to filter out the records.

Also the best known sorting algorithm does it in `O(nlogn)` while iterative record check happen in `O(n)` time.

Thus, first query is faster **here**.

Hope, it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

In my most cases, `SELECT foo FROM table WHERE foo != 0` **is** faster.

But in your case, it *can* be even faster:

```
SELECT foo FROM `table` WHERE foo > 0
```

From the data you've shown, you do not have negative values, so you don't need to check for any. (as pointed out [here - MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html) - scroll to the comments section)

From the [MySQL Distinct docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/distinct-optimization.html):

> In most cases, a DISTINCT clause can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY

So, if performance is an issue and you don't *really* need it, don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM `table`
```

because there is no Where condition

Comment: This is not answering the question. The fact that there is no `where` condition was already a given in the question. Please add an explanation as to why the absence of the `where` clause is more determining than the inclusion of the `distinct` keyword.